# Return list of objects in Hibernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, java-8

I'm writing an application that use Hibernate to query the database (SQL Server).
Now I'm querying a link table for all Items.

The query looks like:

```
"FROM UserRole ur join ur.platformUser join ur.role join ur.company"
```

I need all the UserRoles objects in a list but when I query the above query I got a arrao of objects with UserRole, Role, Company and PlatformUser objects in it.

[image]

I only need the UserRole objects with the other objects in the UserRole object.
How can I solve this in Hiernate that I can cast the result to for ex. `Arraylist<UserRole>`?

I tried following syntax:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select * FROM UserRole ur join PlatformUser pu ON pu.userId = ur.userId join [Role] r ON r.roleId = ur.roleId join [Company] c ON c.companyId = ur.companyId").addEntity(UserRole.class);
```

With this line I got a List of UserRoles but all the underlying objects are NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you've mapped the fields in the UserRole as lazy loaded? (Or haven't specified, I believe lazy loading is the default)

Try writing something along the lines of

```
Object obj = userRoles.get(0).getName(); //Or any of the previously null valued fields you have in there
```

Make sure you're writing this still within session, preferably right after the query.list(); itself

That should lazy load the value, and if that was indeed the case, look into initializing hibernate objects.

edit:
If you're looking for a more proper way of doing this, there's actually a hibernate method that requests to initialize a proxy object, I'm unsure why it's better than just getting the thing you want to initialize from code, but it sure is prettier.

```
Hibernate.initialize(Object initializeMe)
```

But as far as I know, it's a shallow method, meaning it won't load entities inside of this one. To achieve that you'll need to either do it by hand, or make a generic method that'll load everything, think reflection & recursive.